# query regarding touch coordinates on an ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

I have an image in ImageView. I need to know the exact (x,y) coordinate of the image when I touch the image. I also want to draw a circle on the touch place.

Given below, is the code I use. I have an ImageView and I attach a onTouchListener to it.

The problem is this:

1. I get weird (x,y) values
2. new circles are only drawn 3 times. After that no new circles are drawn!

   ```
   ImageView touch=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
   touch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

              //Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
              //Canvas can=new Canvas(bm);
              p.setColor(Color.RED);
              float fx=event.getX();
              float fy=event.getY();
              can.drawCircle(fx, fy, 20, p);                   
           }
           return true;
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you aren't taking into account the fact that the position of the `MotionEvent` is adjusted to be relative to the containing view (the `ImageView` in this case) and it looks like you are attempting to draw them on another `Canvas` which would have a different coordinate space.  If you need the two to be separate like this, I would recommend using `MotionEvent.getRawX()` and `MotionEvent.getRawY()` so that the touch values are in the coordinates of the screen as a whole.

However, if you just want to draw the circles over the image, a better solution would be to subclass `ImageView` so you can detect touches in its `onTouchEvent()` method directly (instead of a listener) and do custom drawing in its `onDraw()` method, guaranteeing everything is in the same adjusted coordinate plane.

It is not apparent from your code why this operation would only work correctly three times.  Perhaps try only returning `true` from the touch detection method in the DOWN instance that you are interested in.  You may be unnecessarily stealing touch events with the current implementation.

HTH

Comment: thanks, worked nicely. I have no idea why it works only 3 times!

Comment: However, if I zoom the image, the drawn circle moves away...the coordinates change... anyway to make the circle draws kind of permanent ?